# What are the rules for XP/gold gained, especially for mission requirements?

Tags: deep-rock-galactic

If the mission is to mine Morkite, and you get *more* Morkite after meeting the quota - does that net gold, XP, or both? Is it reduced?

What about Nitra, in general? Does mining more give any benefit if you don't really need it for resupplys?

Bittergems only give XP and cannot be used in crafting, right? The same with the "error block" mineral?

What about for secondary objectives like Boolo cap? Does getting more get anything?

Comment: I remember reading that each additional main objective (1 morkite, 1 aquarq) and secondary objective gives 1 more xp each. If I can find a source I'll post a proper answer. There's also a big update coming soon which might change this.

Comment: 1 single XP? In a mission where someone might earn 5k -> 25K, that is quite small for things like Aquark. However, I guess it might be worth doing for something like Morkite which has larger quantities. I'll keep an eye on the update, thanks!

Comment: @0xFF Do you have a link to information about this update?

Comment: Not on hand but it's in the Steam news at least. Look for Deep Dives. It's update 25 I think, I'll post more details tonight in my answer.

Comment: See [this post for the update](https://steamcommunity.com/games/DeepRockGalactic/announcements/detail/1609395807153124586).

Comment: It appears the update did not change this for normal rounds. Though apparently in deep dives nitra carries over. Apparently gold isn't counted either on deep dives if I heard right.

Comment: Update: The gold not being saved is a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Primary and secondary resources each give a small amount of xp each according to the [wiki](https://deeprockgalactic.gamepedia.com/Morkite) and kinda confirmed by a moderator on the [steam forum](https://steamcommunity.com/app/548430/discussions/1/1696040635920611449/), though I don't know how reliable that is. I'm pretty sure I've noticed it before but I'll need to test it to be 100% sure.

  - Morkite, hollomite, dystrum : 1 xp each
  - Aquarq : 25 xp each
  - Fossils, apoca bloom, boolo cap: 3 xp each
  - Crafting materials are worth 2 xp each
  - Other items are worth some XP but you can't mine more than the objective
- Nitra doesn't give any rewards and is lost after a mission ends*
- Bitter gems only give some addition credits (like compressed gold).
- Error cubes only give an additional 2000 xp*

***[Update 25](https://steamcommunity.com/games/DeepRockGalactic/announcements/detail/1609395807153124586)**
This update will add Deep Dive missions which consist of 3 missions in a row. Nitra will be  kept between these missions. It has also been hinted that Error cubes will have a use.

---

I did two 1/1 mining missions with booloo caps, not touching any extra minerals.
In one I collected 206 morktite and got 812 xp for minerals, in the other I collected 200 morkite and got 800 xp for minerals. With the +100% bonus from hasard 4 that matches right up. Here's a pic for more details:
[image: extra_morkite]
I'm not sure how exactly the total is calculated though.

Comment: So, in summary: 1. There's no significant advantage to collecting any of the primary or secondary objectives once they're fulfilled, the amounts are too tiny to be significant. 2. Nitra only worth it if needed, though it's almost always needed. 3: Always mine bitter gems, gold/compressed gold, and error cubes.

Comment: Pretty much. Personally I don't bother gathering more that objectives requires aside from morkite when you're in the last room and there's like 6 more deposits than you need.